# Visual Studio 2015 Angular 2 and Angular Material 2

Tags: visual-studio, angular, angular-material2

I'm struggling trying to figure out how to get VS 2015 to build an MVC project with Angular 2 and Angular Material 2. I get error Cannot find name HammerManger when I build.

I've copied all of @angular from node_modules to wwwroot/lib/angular2 and all of @types from node_modules to wwwroot/lib/@types

tsconfig.json

```
 {
  "compilerOptions": {
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "module": "system",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "removeComments": false,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es5"
  },
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "wwwroot/lib"
  ],
  "types": [
    "hammerjs"
  ]
}
```

What am I missing?